# Django open local image

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, django-imagekit

I'm Try to Open local demo image and save to test.jpg
but i getting error like this
the local image open browser using url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/demo.jpg"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\rto\rc\views.py", line 20, in get
    img =Image.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/demo.jpg',mode="r")
  File "E:\django and flutter projects\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2953, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/demo.jpg'
```

This is Simple view.py

```
class PrintRC(APIView):
    def get(self,req):
         img =Image.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/demo.jpg',mode="r")
         img.save('test.jpeg')
         print('Success')
         return Response('hello')
```

Comment: You can't open image via HTTP. Open it via local path instead

Comment: Ok i want insert another image from client to this demo image then save the image so what can i do  thankq

Answer (score 0):

```
class PrintRC(APIView):
    def get(self,req):
         path = Path('media/demo.jpg')
         img =Image.open(path,mode="r")
         img.save('test.jpeg')
         print(img)
         return Response('hello')
```